# Why is EntityFramework Namespace undefined even after installing EntityFramework with Package Manager console?

Tags: orm, namespaces, installation, entity-framework-5, package-managers

All:

We started off our project using ASP.NET Web Forms.

Our ASP.NET C# web application is used in the following environment

```
.NET Framework 4

ASP.NET Web Forms.

IIS 7

Windows 2008

Visual Studio 2010
```

.NET IDE

```
C#

HTTPS ( SSL )
```

We wanted to integrate Microsoft Entity Framework Version 5.
Therefore, from the Package Manager console in Visual Studio 2010, I ran the following command.

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0
You are downloading EntityFramework from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is        available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=253898&clcid=0x409. Check       the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license       agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your         acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license         agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
   Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.
  Successfully added 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' to PivotServer.
```

Type 'get-help EntityFramework' to see all available Entity Framework commands.

As you can see above, it installed EntityFramework 5.0.0 properly.

Also, in my ASP.NET Web application, the installation automatically added EntityFramework dll to the References.

However, if I write the following

"using EntityFramework"

into one of my C# cs files, then it states that the EntityFramework is undefined.

I also Unstall the EntityFramework package, and then reinstall it but it still failed to recogonize the EntityFramework.

Please suggest what steps I have to take in order for EntityFramework namespace to be defined in my ASP.NET web project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no EntityFramework namespace. Use Object Browser to see what namespaces you should use.

Comment: Thanks.  With the EntityFramework.dll that gets installed, we don't get "using EntityFramework" namespace.  However, I found the "EntityFramework.Extended" package installed, and it worked out well.